# Split an array into two Parts

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, for-loop

How can we split or divide an array into two new arrays?

```
SingleARR = [7,5,6,4,3,2,4,5,4,2,8,8];
```

one array should have values that don't repeat
and the other has values that repeat. Moreover, both new arrays should have different elements from each other.

Comment: Please include your code and tell us what's failing so someone can help.

Comment: People seem to be mis-reading the question. I think the result should be two arrays: `[3,6,7]` (the non-repeats) and `[2,4,5,8]` (the repeats).

Comment: @VLAZ The OP wants to split one array into two, not merge two into one.

Comment: @kol thanks for the correction. I somehow COMPLETELY misread the question...

Answer (score 2):

First, count the frequencies. Then filter it by the frequency if it is one then that does not repeat and push it into one array. Then again filter it by the frequency, if it is greater than 1 then it repeats and pushes

```js
 let a = [7, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 2, 8, 8];
    
    let ret = a.reduce((p, c) => {
      if (!p[c]) p[c] = 1;
      else p[c] += 1;
      return p;
    }, {});
    let x = [];
    let y = [];
    console.log(ret);
    for (prop in ret) if (ret[prop] === 1) x.push(+prop);
    for (prop in ret) if (ret[prop] > 1) y.push(+prop);
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
```

it into another array.

Comment: As a general rule, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing, homework-doing service. We should encourage posters to try to solve their problems first, rather than us simply writing all the code for them when they've made no effort.

Comment: For the filtering steps, why not use `Array.prototype.filter()`?